# Bootstrap CSS - Info Box Alignment

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap info box:

```
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center" role="info">
          <span style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle; padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign alert-info" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span style="font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle;" class="alert-info" role="info">Please help support your chosen charity <b>{{ request.session.chosenCharity }}</b> and the str8RED development by signing up for additional benefits.</span>
        </div>
```

This creates the following box:

[image]

As you can see it looks a little clumsy.  I would like the "i" in the circle to be vertically centred in the blue box with the writing to its right but NOT over lapping like it currently does. I have tried using the django grid but it made the "i" and the writing look too far apart.  I tried to use HTML tables but could not get it to match what I am after.

Any thoughts on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `display:flex property;`

Take a look here and you can customize it as you like:

https://www.bootply.com/94SfnOPfd4 and also https://www.bootply.com/KndnEHLYCb

```
<div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;width:300px;display: flex;" role="info">
  <span style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle; padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;float: left;margin: auto;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign alert-info" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span style="font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle;text-align: initial;" class="alert-info" role="info">Please help support your chosen charity <b>chosenCharity</b> and the str8RED development by signing up for additional benefits.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the example, thank you.  Will it be there forever for future people to use or should I add your code to the answer?

Comment: Excellent, if it helps anyone else in the future even better. Take care.

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but it breaks if I change the width from 300px.  Should I put up a separate question?

Comment: what width do you have? can you share link or fiddle so i can fix it?

Comment: If you change your example from 300px to 75% and then stretch the window the text hugs the right hand side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144665/discussion-between-tech-love-and-alan-tingey).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to wrap the info in a div container and add this class info-container.. and apply vertical-align:middle property like the example

```css
.info-container{
   display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% + -50px);
    vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center" role="info">

          <span style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle; padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign alert-info" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          <div class="info-container">
          <span style="font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle;" class="alert-info" role="info">Please help support your chosen charity <b></b> and the str8RED development by signing up for additionalPlease help support your chosen charity <b></b> and the str8RED development by signing up for additionalPlease help support your chosen charity <b></b> and the str8RED development by signing up for additionalPlease help support your chosen charity <b></b> and the str8RED development by signing up for additional benefits.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```